# Using live Linux or custom distros as backup?

Tags: backup, live-usb, distributions, clone

There are tools such as [`Remastersys`](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Remastersys/) (and possibly also [`Linux Live kit`](https://www.linux-live.org/)) for creating custom distros and live Linux systems. Is it possible to use them to create a **complete** system backup, i.e. preserving *all configurations, group policies, security settings, network configurations (proxies, VPNs)* etc.? Down to what level of detail is the source system reproduced, is it just the `/home` folder + user packages, or is it equivalent to a complete clone/image of the entire hard drive incl. partition structure? Does disk encryption have an effect, e.g. having `LUKS` on `LVM`?

PS.: FWIW, here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6sAl.png) of `gnome-disk` with partition information.

Comment: Is it OK for you to shutdown your system and boot from another drive, for example a USB pendrive? In that case [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org) can do it for you. It is smart enough to copy only used blocks in the file systems (and skip free blocks), and there is compression, if you backup to an image. Clonezilla will also backup the bootloader and partition table. A clonezilla image is a directory with a set of files.

Comment: @sudodus: Thx for this bit! If `clonezilla` also backs up the bootlader and partition table, would that make the image bootable? I.e. could I boot the backup directly from the pen drive?

Comment: Yes, it works. I have used this method for years, and I have restored from the backup to a fresh drive (of at least the same size, not one single byte smaller). Do not boot with both the original drive and the cloned copy connected - it can damage both systems! But when the original drive is removed, or if you restore from the backup to the original drive, it will boot (and behave exactly like the system that was backed up. *But you boot from the restored system*, which is usually not in a pendrive but in an SSD or HDD.

Comment: Instead of making a [compressed] image, you can clone directly to another drive (of at least the same size, not one single byte smaller). Then you can replace the original drive with the cloned copy and it will work just like the original one.

Comment: Thx, I think this could work! So one should not boot, when both bootable drives (with functionally identical content) are plugged into the same machine? Meaning that I can boot *either* from the source *or* the clone, as long as they're not mounted to the same machine?

Comment: Yes - The problem when both are connected is that they are identical, evem the UUIDs of the file systems, so there will be confusion. But when only one of them, the original or the cloned copy is connected, things will work correctly.

Comment: *"Instead of making a [compressed] image, you can clone directly to another drive (of at least the same size, not one single byte smaller)."* => Does, for `clonezilla`, mean "compressed" = "sparse" or is compression an additional feature? I would like to avoid compression, as this will add another layer of scrambling to the data, collapsing the unused space would already suffice, as only a few GB of the HDD space is used and the rest is unused space

Comment: But you should play safe - so test that you get everything correct, test that the backup really works now. Do not wait until the original drive fails, it might be too late to fix a failed backup.

Comment: I think compression is automatic when you create an image, but when you clone directly, there will be no compression. (But I think it is a waste of drive space, so I store compressed images.) You pick the method that works best for you :-)

Comment: Okay, but `clonezilla` will omit unused space in any case? Thx again :)

Comment: Yes, it is smart enough to skip over the unused blocks in the file systems. The used blocks will be written at the correct locations.

Comment: Perfect, will try this! You should write this into an answer (if you like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Clonezilla can create a complete image or cloned copy for you

[**Clonezilla**](https://clonezilla.org/) is smart enough to copy only used blocks in the file systems (and skip free blocks), and there is compression, if you backup to an image. Clonezilla will also backup the bootloader and partition table. A clonezilla image is a directory with a set of files.

I have used this method for years, and I have restored from the backup to a fresh drive (of at least the same size, not one single byte smaller). Do not boot with both the original drive and the cloned copy connected - it can damage both systems! But when the original drive is removed, or if you restore from the backup to the original drive, it will boot (and behave exactly like the system that was backed up.

Instead of making a [compressed] image, you can clone directly to another drive (of at least the same size, not one single byte smaller). Then you can replace the original drive with the cloned copy and it will work just like the original one.

I think compression is automatic when you create an image, but when you clone directly, there will be no compression. (I think a cloned copy is a waste of drive space, so I store compressed images.) You pick the method that works best for *you*.

Finally, you should play safe - so **test** that you get everything correct, test that the backup really works now. Do not wait until the original drive fails, it might be too late to fix a failed backup

Comment: Thx! Btw, it would be interesting to see how skipping of free blocks and bootability goes together. Do I understand it correctly, that only the direct clone (requiring at least the same size target drive) is bootable, but not the compressed backup?

Comment: The compressed image itself is only a directory with some some files, but Clonezilla can **restore** a perfectly bootable cloned copy from that image into a target drive. This restored copy works in the same way as what is created by a direct cloning operation. If you have enough time, you can test both methods.

Comment: With encrypted disk Clonezilla cannot identify free blocks, so there will be no speed up and no efficient compression. In other words, a compressed image will lose some of its advantages, and you might go directly to a cloned image.